# How to see the output of a query which is executed remotely from mysql command line tool?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, command-prompt

I am using mysql command line tool to connect to a mysql server present on a remote machine using following command :
 
`mysql -u username -ppassword -h host_ip -P port_no --verbose < sql file on windows`
I have a .sql file on windows that i execute on the remote server. I have used verbose to display the sql commands that are present in the file and that are being executed.
 Now the problem is that when I execute the above command, if the execution is successful it just returns the prompt back and when there is an error it shows the error. What i want is that when a command is successful it should show the response that is given by the server like if you execute the following command in mysql :
`create table xyz;`
 after executing the above command, mysql returns **"table xyz created successfully"**. I want something like this to be shown on my command line prompt.
I have used -E option also but it doesn't work.

### Edited

To execute the above mysql commands, i have downloaded "Windows (x86, xx-bit), ZIP Archive" and then changed the current directory in command prompt to the bin folder present in the above downloaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execution of every select statement returns either success or failure. And in case of DDL/DML statements it returns number of rows affected. You should capture those values after executing each and every statement to show results verbosely.

***Example on CREATE TABLE statement results capturing***:
In your SQL script file, next to every executable statement add a statement similar to the following.

```
select concat('table x ', if(row_count()=0, '', 'not '), 'created' ) 'result';
```

***Working Example***:
Let us say you have written following statements in a script file `mysql_stmt.sql` on `Desktop`.

```
select row_count();
create table y( x in6 );
select concat('table y ', if(row_count()=0, '', 'not '), 'created' ) 'result';
create table y( x int );
select concat('table y ', if(row_count()=0, '', 'not '), 'created' ) 'result';

-- C:\Users\Ravinder\Desktop\mysql_stmt.sql
```

At the MySQL command prompt, issue following command:

```
\. C:\Users\Ravinder\Desktop\mysql_stmt.sql
```

You will see the verbosely results on your screen.

***Example from Shell prompt***:
It would be the same behaviour at Shell prompt too. But the execution aborts in case if you have any wrong queries syntactically or constraint violating statements, etc. In such cases you may require to do more exercise in identifying and fixing the issues. You may also have options to suppress such failures and instruct to proceed to next statement, but I am not sure and not tried.

```
MyShell>mysql -u root -p --verbose test < "C:\Users\Ravinder\Desktop\mysql_stmt.sql"
Enter password: *****
--------------
select row_count()
--------------

row_count()
-1
--------------
create table y( x int )
--------------

--------------
select concat('table y ', if(row_count()=0, '', 'not '), 'created' ) 'result'
--------------

result
table y created

MyShell>
```

Comment: actually i cannot make changes to the sql files. I was looking for the options that i can use in the command "mysql -u username -ppassword -h host_ip -P port_no --verbose < sql file on windows" so the result is displayed in command prompt only.

Comment: when i use the command mentioned in the previous comment i don't get mysql prompt, i just get back my normal prompt when queries in the file get executed.

Comment: That is the shell prompt, say `C:\Users\Kratos>`. For the success state echoing you must add statements, as explained by me, in your script file. Otherwise no.